# AutoFixtures and how to use them

Tags: c#, sitecore, autofixture

I am currently working with unittesting using autofixtures.

I have this class [media](https://pastebin.com/MFvTqjDF)

which i want to create with random values, I was told this could be done using autofixtures -

So I tried using of of its public constructor namely  Media(MediaData mediaData),

as such:

```
                MediaItem anonymousData = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MediaItem>();
                Media media = new Media(new MediaData(anonymousData));
```

Problem with this is, that the subitem ->  media.MediaData.MediaItem.InnerItem;
doesn't not get set.

I then tried to go a level down again: as [MediaData](https://pastebin.com/Q3wsPTPu) has a public constructor `public MediaData(MediaItem [mediaItem][3])` which I could use Instead so i tried this

```
            MediaItem anonymousData = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MediaItem>();
            Media media = new Media(new MediaData(anonymousData));
```

but this gives an error: 
Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='databaseName2df4ec17-4d66-41bf-aa2f-75ed1ddd266a']

I just trying to generate a valid Media item,  media.MediaData.MediaItem.InnerItem;

How do make one using autofixture, without keep going down the rabbit hole?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the most issues you observe is the very wide `Item` API, implemented by Sitecore. I would recommend you taking a look at the [Sitecore.NSubstituteUtils](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sitecore.NSubstituteUtils/) library which makes item faking much easier. After that you can configure your fixture to generate `Item` and `Database` instance using the library:

```
fixture.Inject(FakeUtil.FakeDatabase());
fixture.Register((Database db) => new FakeItem(database: db));
fixture.Register((FakeItem fakeItem) => fakeItem.ToSitecoreItem());
```

This should do a trick.

As a bonus you will also get a nice fluent interface to configure various item aspects (like fields, templates, presentation, etc).